# How to make async/wait inside of for loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using async await inside of for loop as below.

```
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i += 1) {
  try{
    const client = await axios.get(
      `${process.env.user}/client/${result[i].id}`
    );
  } catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
    if (client.data.success === true) {
      result[i].Name = rider.data.client.Name;
      result[i].PhoneNumber = rider.data.client.Number;
    }
  }
```

But I want to make this using 'new Promise' and 'promiss.all' to make it asynclously.
But I don'k know how to make this correctly doing error handle well.
Could you recommend some advice for this? Thank you for reading it.

Comment: `async/await` also returns a promise

Comment: Do you want to break all processing if any client failed, or skip failed data and get only correctly fetched clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a basic solution, i think

```
let playList = []
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i += 1) {
    playList.push(axios.get(
        `${process.env.user}/client/${result[i].id}`
    ).then(res => {
        if (res.data.success === true) {
            result[i].Name = rider.data.client.Name;
            result[i].PhoneNumber = rider.data.client.Number;
        }
    }).catch(ex => console.log(ex)));
}
await Promise.all(playList)
```

This can also be done by using a foreach loop.
The for/foreach loop can be simplified by using a map function.
Js map function is equivalent of c# select linq function.
The fat arrow in js map function is not bound to return a value unlike c# select inner function which must return a value.

```
await Promise.all(result.map(async r => {
        let client;
        try {
            client = await axios.get(`${process.env.user}/client/${r.id}`);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
        if (client.data.success === true) {
            r.Name = rider.data.client.Name;
            r.PhoneNumber = rider.data.client.Number;
        }
    }));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But why playList needs in this case?

Comment: Playlist is the array of promises, which will be awaited with Promise.all method.
Promise.all needs a collection of promises to work. It will start all promises at the same time, and will resolve when the slowest promise is done.

Comment: You can simplify the code by using a map function. map is the equivalent c# linq select function. this type of functions iterates the elements of a collection and executes a given function on it.
I wrote the expanded version because is easier to get i think.

I'll add the compressed version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var promises = result.map(r => axios.get(`${process.env.user}/client/${r.id}`);

Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
   console.log('All promises done');
});
```

The idea is that if you are awaiting something, that is promise, you can await it, or call it to get promise

Example:

```
function Foo()
{
    return new Promise(...); // Promise of int for example
}
```

you can do

```
var p = Foo(); //you will get promise
```

Or

```
var v = await Foo(); // you will get int value when promise resolved
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it with `async/await` + `Promise.all`:

```js
const myResult = await Promise.all(result.map(({ id }) => {
  return axios.get(`${process.env.user}/client/${id}`);
}));

// deal with the result of those requests
const parsed = myResult.map(data => /* your code here */);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `Array.map` to call your function along with `Promise.all`. I wrapped the axios request in a function so if one of your request fails, it wont stop every other requests. If you don't mind stopping when you got an issue, look at others answers to your question.

```js
function fakeRequest() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({
        data: {
          success: true,
          
          client: {
             Name: 'Todd',
             Number: 5,
          },
        },
      });
    }, 300);
  });
}

(async() => {
  const result = [{}, {}, {}];

  await Promise.all(result.map(async(x, xi) => {
    try {
      const client = await fakeRequest();

      if (client.data.success === true) {
        result[xi].Name = client.data.client.Name;
        result[xi].PhoneNumber = client.data.client.Number;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }));
  
  console.log(result);
})();
```